Android Studio creates templates that can not launch. Apps crash imediately
Plase help to pinpoint a solution to a bug of a Xiaomi MIUI 13 phone that makes it impossible to create any app for me. I don't know how to describe the problem in a more technical way, sorry for long read.
The problem: any basic template available in Android studio crashes when launched specifically on the  aforementioned phone. In emulator and other phones the self-made apps launch fine.
I only create new project (no edits to android studio's default code template), build a  debug-signed APK, copy APK to the phone, install and run. App crashes.
Apps made by other developers work flawlessly. The problem is only with apps I try to build via Android Studio.
The problematic firmware: MIUI 13.0.3 based on Anroid 12 api 31
What has been done:

tried multiple app templates in Android studio: empty views activity, basic views activity, bottom navigation views activity, etc.
tried Android Studio Iguana and Android Studio Chipmunk

The error log is for the empty views activity template

    package com.emptyviewsactivity;

    import android.os.Bundle;

    import androidx.activity.EdgeToEdge;
    import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
    import androidx.core.graphics.Insets;
    import androidx.core.view.ViewCompat;
    import androidx.core.view.WindowInsetsCompat;

    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        EdgeToEdge.enable(this);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        ViewCompat.setOnApplyWindowInsetsListener(findViewById(R.id.main), (v, insets) -> {
            Insets systemBars = insets.getInsets(WindowInsetsCompat.Type.systemBars());
            v.setPadding(systemBars.left, systemBars.top, systemBars.right, systemBars.bottom);
            return insets;
            });
        }
    }

---------------------------- PROCESS STARTED (25468) for package com.emptyviewsactivity ----------------------------
2024-10-21 04:32:08.586 25468-25491 AppScoutStateMachine    com.emptyviewsactivity               D  25468-ScoutStateMachinecreated
2024-10-21 04:32:08.602  2263-2501  ActivityManagerWrapper  com.miui.home                        E  getRecentTasks: mainTaskId=1477   userId=0   baseIntent=Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN flag=268435456 cmp=ComponentInfo{com.emptyviewsactivity/com.emptyviewsactivity.MainActivity} }
2024-10-21 04:32:08.739 25468-25468 GraphicsEnvironment     com.emptyviewsactivity               V  ANGLE Developer option for 'com.emptyviewsactivity' set to: 'default'
2024-10-21 04:32:08.739 25468-25468 GraphicsEnvironment     com.emptyviewsactivity               V  Neither updatable production driver nor prerelease driver is supported.
2024-10-21 04:32:08.743 25468-25468 ForceDarkHelperStubImpl com.emptyviewsactivity               I  initialize for com.emptyviewsactivity , ForceDarkOrigin
2024-10-21 04:32:08.744 25468-25468 OpenGLRenderer          com.emptyviewsactivity               D  JNI_OnLoad success
2024-10-21 04:32:08.744 25468-25468 MiuiForceDarkConfig     com.emptyviewsactivity               I  setConfig density:2.750000, mainRule:0, secondaryRule:0, tertiaryRule:0
2024-10-21 04:32:08.746 25468-25468 NetworkSecurityConfig   com.emptyviewsactivity               D  No Network Security Config specified, using platform default
2024-10-21 04:32:08.747 25468-25468 NetworkSecurityConfig   com.emptyviewsactivity               D  No Network Security Config specified, using platform default
2024-10-21 04:32:08.776 25468-25498 libMEOW                 com.emptyviewsactivity               D  meow new tls: 0xb40000788b261140
2024-10-21 04:32:08.776 25468-25498 libMEOW                 com.emptyviewsactivity               D  meow reload base cfg path: na
2024-10-21 04:32:08.776 25468-25498 libMEOW                 com.emptyviewsactivity               D  meow reload overlay cfg path: na
2024-10-21 04:32:08.777 25468-25498 QT                      com.emptyviewsactivity               E  [QT]file does not exist
2024-10-21 04:32:08.778 25468-25498 libMEOW                 com.emptyviewsactivity               D  applied 1 plugins for [com.emptyviewsactivity]:
2024-10-21 04:32:08.778 25468-25498 libMEOW                 com.emptyviewsactivity               D    plugin 1: [libMEOW_gift.so]:
2024-10-21 04:32:08.778 25468-25498 libMEOW                 com.emptyviewsactivity               D  meow delete tls: 0xb40000788b261140
2024-10-21 04:32:08.812 25468-25468 AppCompatDelegate       com.emptyviewsactivity               D  Checking for metadata for AppLocalesMetadataHolderService : Service not found
2024-10-21 04:32:08.837 25468-25468 libc                    com.emptyviewsactivity               A  Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR), fault addr 0x0 in tid 25468 (tyviewsactivity), pid 25468 (tyviewsactivity)
2024-10-21 04:32:09.050 25501-25501 DEBUG                   pid-25501                            A  Cmdline: com.emptyviewsactivity
2024-10-21 04:32:09.050 25501-25501 DEBUG                   pid-25501                            A  pid: 25468, tid: 25468, name: tyviewsactivity  >>> com.emptyviewsactivity <<<
2024-10-21 04:32:09.051 25501-25501 DEBUG                   pid-25501                            A        #117 pc 0000000000227f40  [anon:dalvik-classes.dex extracted in memory from /data/app/~~-9Evx2EYPU5vWd5C6F1RXg==/com.emptyviewsactivity-KTljstK-yl2CE2BjY5XL4Q==/base.apk] (androidx.core.content.ContextCompat$Api21Impl.getDrawable+0)
2024-10-21 04:32:09.051 25501-25501 DEBUG                   pid-25501                            A        #123 pc 00000000002287de  [anon:dalvik-classes.dex extracted in memory from /data/app/~~-9Evx2EYPU5vWd5C6F1RXg==/com.emptyviewsactivity-KTljstK-yl2CE2BjY5XL4Q==/base.apk] (androidx.core.content.ContextCompat.getDrawable+2)
2024-10-21 04:32:09.051 25501-25501 DEBUG                   pid-25501                            A        #129 pc 0000000000182dbe  [anon:dalvik-classes.dex extracted in memory from /data/app/~~-9Evx2EYPU5vWd5C6F1RXg==/com.emptyviewsactivity-KTljstK-yl2CE2BjY5XL4Q==/base.apk] (androidx.appcompat.widget.ResourceManagerInternal.getDrawable+34)
2024-10-21 04:32:09.051 25501-25501 DEBUG                   pid-25501                            A        #135 pc 0000000000182d6c  [anon:dalvik-classes.dex extracted in memory from /data/app/~~-9Evx2EYPU5vWd5C6F1RXg==/com.emptyviewsactivity-KTljstK-yl2CE2BjY5XL4Q==/base.apk] (androidx.appcompat.widget.ResourceManagerInternal.getDrawable+4)
2024-10-21 04:32:09.051 25501-25501 DEBUG                   pid-25501                            A        #141 pc 00000000001832c4  [anon:dalvik-classes.dex extracted in memory from /data/app/~~-9Evx2EYPU5vWd5C6F1RXg==/com.emptyviewsactivity-KTljstK-yl2CE2BjY5XL4Q==/base.apk] (androidx.appcompat.widget.ResourceManagerInternal.checkVectorDrawableSetup+20)
2024-10-21 04:32:09.052 25501-25501 DEBUG                   pid-25501                            A        #147 pc 0000000000182d9e  [anon:dalvik-classes.dex extracted in memory from /data/app/~~-9Evx2EYPU5vWd5C6F1RXg==/com.emptyviewsactivity-KTljstK-yl2CE2BjY5XL4Q==/base.apk] (androidx.appcompat.widget.ResourceManagerInternal.getDrawable+2)
2024-10-21 04:32:09.052 25501-25501 DEBUG                   pid-25501                            A        #153 pc 0000000000173d42  [anon:dalvik-classes.dex extracted in memory from /data/app/~~-9Evx2EYPU5vWd5C6F1RXg==/com.emptyviewsactivity-KTljstK-yl2CE2BjY5XL4Q==/base.apk] (androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager.getDrawable+6)
2024-10-21 04:32:09.052 25501-25501 DEBUG                   pid-25501                            A        #159 pc 000000000018b030  [anon:dalvik-classes.dex extracted in memory from /data/app/~~-9Evx2EYPU5vWd5C6F1RXg==/com.emptyviewsactivity-KTljstK-yl2CE2BjY5XL4Q==/base.apk] (androidx.appcompat.widget.TintTypedArray.getDrawableIfKnown+48)
2024-10-21 04:32:09.052 25501-25501 DEBUG                   pid-25501                            A        #165 pc 00000000001551d4  [anon:dalvik-classes.dex extracted in memory from /data/app/~~-9Evx2EYPU5vWd5C6F1RXg==/com.emptyviewsactivity-KTljstK-yl2CE2BjY5XL4Q==/base.apk] (androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.attachToWindow+72)
2024-10-21 04:32:09.052 25501-25501 DEBUG                   pid-25501                            A        #171 pc 0000000000155634  [anon:dalvik-classes.dex extracted in memory from /data/app/~~-9Evx2EYPU5vWd5C6F1RXg==/com.emptyviewsactivity-KTljstK-yl2CE2BjY5XL4Q==/base.apk] (androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.ensureWindow+36)
2024-10-21 04:32:09.052 25501-25501 DEBUG                   pid-25501                            A        #177 pc 0000000000155842  [anon:dalvik-classes.dex extracted in memory from /data/app/~~-9Evx2EYPU5vWd5C6F1RXg==/com.emptyviewsactivity-KTljstK-yl2CE2BjY5XL4Q==/base.apk] (androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.onCreate+14)
2024-10-21 04:32:09.052 25501-25501 DEBUG                   pid-25501                            A        #183 pc 00000000001509e2  [anon:dalvik-classes.dex extracted in memory from /data/app/~~-9Evx2EYPU5vWd5C6F1RXg==/com.emptyviewsactivity-KTljstK-yl2CE2BjY5XL4Q==/base.apk] (androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity$2.onContextAvailable+42)
2024-10-21 04:32:09.052 25501-25501 DEBUG                   pid-25501                            A        #189 pc 000000000014a406  [anon:dalvik-classes.dex extracted in memory from /data/app/~~-9Evx2EYPU5vWd5C6F1RXg==/com.emptyviewsactivity-KTljstK-yl2CE2BjY5XL4Q==/base.apk] (androidx.activity.contextaware.ContextAwareHelper.dispatchOnContextAvailable+50)
2024-10-21 04:32:09.052 25501-25501 DEBUG                   pid-25501                            A        #195 pc 000000000014774a  [anon:dalvik-classes.dex extracted in memory from /data/app/~~-9Evx2EYPU5vWd5C6F1RXg==/com.emptyviewsactivity-KTljstK-yl2CE2BjY5XL4Q==/base.apk] (androidx.activity.ComponentActivity.onCreate+14)
2024-10-21 04:32:09.052 25501-25501 DEBUG                   pid-25501                            A        #201 pc 000000000028b48c  [anon:dalvik-classes.dex extracted in memory from /data/app/~~-9Evx2EYPU5vWd5C6F1RXg==/com.emptyviewsactivity-KTljstK-yl2CE2BjY5XL4Q==/base.apk] (androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity.onCreate+0)
2024-10-21 04:32:09.052 25501-25501 DEBUG                   pid-25501                            A        #207 pc 0000000000000338  [anon:dalvik-classes3.dex extracted in memory from /data/app/~~-9Evx2EYPU5vWd5C6F1RXg==/com.emptyviewsactivity-KTljstK-yl2CE2BjY5XL4Q==/base.apk!classes3.dex] (com.emptyviewsactivity.MainActivity.onCreate+0)
---------------------------- PROCESS ENDED (25468) for package com.emptyviewsactivity ----------------------------
2024-10-21 04:32:09.268  2263-2501  ActivityManagerWrapper  com.miui.home                        E  getRecentTasks: mainTaskId=1477   userId=0   baseIntent=Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN flag=268435456 cmp=ComponentInfo{com.emptyviewsactivity/com.emptyviewsactivity.MainActivity} }

The AndroidManifest.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0"
    android:compileSdkVersion="34"
    android:compileSdkVersionCodename="14"
    package="com.emptyviewsactivity"
    platformBuildVersionCode="34"
    platformBuildVersionName="14">

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="26"
        android:targetSdkVersion="34" />

    <permission
        android:name="com.emptyviewsactivity.DYNAMIC_RECEIVER_NOT_EXPORTED_PERMISSION"
        android:protectionLevel="0x2" />

    <uses-permission
        android:name="com.emptyviewsactivity.DYNAMIC_RECEIVER_NOT_EXPORTED_PERMISSION" />

    <application
        android:theme="@ref/0x7f100228"
        android:label="@ref/0x7f0f001c"
        android:icon="@ref/0x7f0d0000"
        android:debuggable="true"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:extractNativeLibs="false"
        android:fullBackupContent="@ref/0x7f120000"
        android:roundIcon="@ref/0x7f0d0001"
        android:appComponentFactory="androidx.core.app.CoreComponentFactory"
        android:dataExtractionRules="@ref/0x7f120001">

        <activity
            android:name="com.emptyviewsactivity.MainActivity"
            android:exported="true">

            <intent-filter>

                <action
                    android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category
                    android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <service
            android:name="androidx.appcompat.app.AppLocalesMetadataHolderService"
            android:permission="android.permission.BIND_LOCALE_SERVICE"
            android:exported="false">

            <intent-filter>

                <action
                    android:name="androidx.appcompat.app.action.LOCALE_CHANGE" />
            </intent-filter>
        </service>

        <provider
            android:name="androidx.startup.InitializationProvider"
            android:exported="false"
            android:authorities="com.emptyviewsactivity.androidx-startup">

            <meta-data
                android:name="androidx.emoji2.text.EmojiCompatInitializer"
                android:value="androidx.startup" />

            <meta-data
                android:name="androidx.lifecycle.ProcessLifecycleInitializer"
                android:value="androidx.startup" />

            <meta-data
                android:name="androidx.profileinstaller.ProfileInstallerInitializer"
                android:value="androidx.startup" />
        </provider>

        <receiver
            android:name="androidx.profileinstaller.ProfileInstallReceiver"
            android:permission="android.permission.DUMP"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="true"
            android:directBootAware="false">

            <intent-filter>

                <action
                    android:name="androidx.profileinstaller.action.INSTALL_PROFILE" />
            </intent-filter>

            <intent-filter>

                <action
                    android:name="androidx.profileinstaller.action.SKIP_FILE" />
            </intent-filter>

            <intent-filter>

                <action
                    android:name="androidx.profileinstaller.action.SAVE_PROFILE" />
            </intent-filter>

            <intent-filter>

                <action
                    android:name="androidx.profileinstaller.action.BENCHMARK_OPERATION" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
    </application>
</manifest>

After adding to AndroidManifest.xml the service androidx.appcompat.app.AppLocalesMetadataHolderService app still crashes
        <service
            android:name="androidx.appcompat.app.AppLocalesMetadataHolderService"
            android:exported="false"
            android:permission="android.permission.BIND_LOCALE_SERVICE">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="androidx.appcompat.app.action.LOCALE_CHANGE" />
            </intent-filter>
        </service>

the error log
2024-10-21 18:26:40.936   884-6446  BufferQueueDebug        surfaceflinger                       E  [Splash Screen com.emptyviewsactivity#0](this:0xb400007e2a9138d0,id:-1,api:0,p:-1,c:-1) id info cannot be read from 'Splash Screen com.emptyviewsactivity#0'

---------------------------- PROCESS STARTED (26626) for package com.emptyviewsactivity ----------------------------

2024-10-21 18:26:41.009 26626-26646 AppScoutStateMachine    com.emptyviewsactivity               D  26626-ScoutStateMachinecreated

2024-10-21 18:26:41.038  2263-2501  ActivityManagerWrapper  com.miui.home                        E  getRecentTasks: mainTaskId=1504   userId=0   baseIntent=Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN flag=270532608 cmp=ComponentInfo{com.emptyviewsactivity/com.emptyviewsactivity.MainActivity} }

2024-10-21 18:26:41.157 26626-26626 GraphicsEnvironment     com.emptyviewsactivity               V  ANGLE Developer option for 'com.emptyviewsactivity' set to: 'default'

2024-10-21 18:26:41.157 26626-26626 GraphicsEnvironment     com.emptyviewsactivity               V  Neither updatable production driver nor prerelease driver is supported.

2024-10-21 18:26:41.160 26626-26626 ForceDarkHelperStubImpl com.emptyviewsactivity               I  initialize for com.emptyviewsactivity , ForceDarkOrigin

2024-10-21 18:26:41.162 26626-26626 OpenGLRenderer          com.emptyviewsactivity               D  JNI_OnLoad success

2024-10-21 18:26:41.162 26626-26626 MiuiForceDarkConfig     com.emptyviewsactivity               I  setConfig density:2.750000, mainRule:0, secondaryRule:0, tertiaryRule:0

2024-10-21 18:26:41.164 26626-26626 NetworkSecurityConfig   com.emptyviewsactivity               D  No Network Security Config specified, using platform default

2024-10-21 18:26:41.164 26626-26626 NetworkSecurityConfig   com.emptyviewsactivity               D  No Network Security Config specified, using platform default

2024-10-21 18:26:41.191 26626-26655 libMEOW                 com.emptyviewsactivity               D  meow new tls: 0xb40000788b280e00

2024-10-21 18:26:41.191 26626-26655 libMEOW                 com.emptyviewsactivity               D  meow reload base cfg path: na

2024-10-21 18:26:41.191 26626-26655 libMEOW                 com.emptyviewsactivity               D  meow reload overlay cfg path: na

2024-10-21 18:26:41.192 26626-26655 QT                      com.emptyviewsactivity               E  [QT]file does not exist

2024-10-21 18:26:41.192 26626-26655 libMEOW                 com.emptyviewsactivity               D  applied 1 plugins for [com.emptyviewsactivity]:

2024-10-21 18:26:41.192 26626-26655 libMEOW                 com.emptyviewsactivity               D    plugin 1: [libMEOW_gift.so]:

2024-10-21 18:26:41.192 26626-26655 libMEOW                 com.emptyviewsactivity               D  meow delete tls: 0xb40000788b280e00

2024-10-21 18:26:41.227 26626-26626 AndroidRuntime          com.emptyviewsactivity               D  Shutting down VM

2024-10-21 18:26:41.228 26626-26626 AndroidRuntime          com.emptyviewsactivity               E  FATAL EXCEPTION: main

                                                                                                    Process: com.emptyviewsactivity, PID: 26626

                                                                                                    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.emptyviewsactivity/com.emptyviewsactivity.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean java.lang.Boolean.booleanValue()' on a null object reference

                                                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(Unknown Source:877)

                                                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(Unknown Source:89)

                                                                                                        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(Unknown Source:14)

                                                                                                        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(Unknown Source:77)

                                                                                                        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(Unknown Source:73)

                                                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(Unknown Source:159)

                                                                                                        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Unknown Source:19)

                                                                                                        at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Unknown Source:176)

                                                                                                        at android.os.Looper.loop(Unknown Source:76)

                                                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(Unknown Source:147)

                                                                                                        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)

                                                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Unknown Source:11)

                                                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(Unknown Source:316)

                                                                                                    Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean java.lang.Boolean.booleanValue()' on a null object reference

                                                                                                        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegate.isAutoStorageOptedIn(AppCompatDelegate.java:926)

                                                                                                        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.attachBaseContext2(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:398)

                                                                                                        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.attachBaseContext(AppCompatActivity.java:141)

                                                                                                        at android.app.Activity.attach(Unknown Source:8)

                                                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(Unknown Source:518)

                                                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(Unknown Source:89) 

                                                                                                        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(Unknown Source:14) 

                                                                                                        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(Unknown Source:77) 

                                                                                                        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(Unknown Source:73) 

                                                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(Unknown Source:159) 

                                                                                                        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Unknown Source:19) 

                                                                                                        at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Unknown Source:176) 

                                                                                                        at android.os.Looper.loop(Unknown Source:76) 

                                                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(Unknown Source:147) 

                                                                                                        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 

                                                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Unknown Source:11) 

                                                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(Unknown Source:316) 

2024-10-21 18:26:41.228 26626-26626 tyviewsactivity         com.emptyviewsactivity               W  type=1400 audit(0.0:94260): avc: denied { search } for name="mqsas" dev="dm-5" ino=26073 scontext=u:r:untrusted_app:s0:c11,c257,c512,c768 tcontext=u:object_r:mqsas_data_file:s0 tclass=dir permissive=0 app=com.emptyviewsactivity

2024-10-21 18:26:41.230 26626-26626 OOMEventManagerFK       com.emptyviewsactivity               W  Failed to mkdir /data/mqsas/hprof/

2024-10-21 18:26:41.228 26626-26626 tyviewsactivity         com.emptyviewsactivity               W  type=1400 audit(0.0:94261): avc: denied { search } for name="mqsas" dev="dm-5" ino=26073 scontext=u:r:untrusted_app:s0:c11,c257,c512,c768 tcontext=u:object_r:mqsas_data_file:s0 tclass=dir permissive=0 app=com.emptyviewsactivity

2024-10-21 18:26:41.228 26626-26626 tyviewsactivity         com.emptyviewsactivity               W  type=1400 audit(0.0:94262): avc: denied { search } for name="mqsas" dev="dm-5" ino=26073 scontext=u:r:untrusted_app:s0:c11,c257,c512,c768 tcontext=u:object_r:mqsas_data_file:s0 tclass=dir permissive=0 app=com.emptyviewsactivity

2024-10-21 18:26:41.228 26626-26626 tyviewsactivity         com.emptyviewsactivity               W  type=1400 audit(0.0:94263): avc: denied { search } for name="mqsas" dev="dm-5" ino=26073 scontext=u:r:untrusted_app:s0:c11,c257,c512,c768 tcontext=u:object_r:mqsas_data_file:s0 tclass=dir permissive=0 app=com.emptyviewsactivity

2024-10-21 18:26:41.344   884-919   BufferQueueDebug        surfaceflinger                       E  [Application Error: com.emptyviewsactivity#0](this:0xb400007e43a968d0,id:-1,api:0,p:-1,c:-1) id info cannot be read from 'Application Error: com.emptyviewsactivity#0'

2024-10-21 18:26:41.854  2263-2501  ActivityManagerWrapper  com.miui.home                        E  getRecentTasks: mainTaskId=1504   userId=0   baseIntent=Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN flag=270532608 cmp=ComponentInfo{com.emptyviewsactivity/com.emptyviewsactivity.MainActivity} }

---------------------------- PROCESS ENDED (26626) for package com.emptyviewsactivity ----------------------------


AS Chipmunk was released in before the final version of Android 12, therefore I would consider it as to old, but Iguana was released in 2023, therefore it should be new enough.

The main problem seems to be Checking for metadata for AppLocalesMetadataHolderService : Service not found - Use Android Studio APK analyzer and check AndroidManifest.xml if it contains a <service> entry for androidx.appcompat.app.AppLocalesMetadataHolderService.

Robert, hi! thank you for your efforts to help! I have added the service entry you mentioned, but I am unable to paste AndroidManifest.xml in this reply, so it has been added to initial post. However, the app keeps crashing. Any other ideas where to look?

I would assume a problem with your device. Try a different device or perform a factory reset on the device.
